# PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream for informix JDBC driver

Tags: database, jdbc, blob, informix

I'm using following function to set a binary stream value to a prepared statement.

```
void setBlobValue(String value, PreparedStatement prepStmt, int index) throws SQLException, IOException {
    if (value != null) {
        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(CharacterEncoder.getSafeText(value).getBytes());
        if (inputStream != null) {
            prepStmt.setBinaryStream(index, inputStream, inputStream.available());
        } else {
            prepStmt.setBinaryStream(index, inputStream, 0);
        }
    } else {
        prepStmt.setBinaryStream(index, null, 0);
    }
}
```

I use this function to set prepared statements for H2, mysql, mssql, oracle, oracle_rac, DB2 and informix databases. When using informix and sending `null` as the Value, `setBinaryStream` method gives a `NullPointerException` even though in other databases it works properly.

What is the reason for this? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: The reason is probably that it is a bug in the driver, try using [`setNull`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull-int-int-) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by

```
prepStmt.setBinaryStream(index, new ByteArrayInputStream(CharacterEncoder.getSafeText("").getBytes()), 0);
```

This is a bug of currrent informix dirver. Follwoting are two more workarounds.

```
setNULL(1,IfxTypes.IFX_TYPE_BLOB)

setObject(1,null)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is bug in Informix JDBC driver.

You already check if `inputStream` is `null` so I think it is better to use `setNull()` instead of `setBinaryStream()`:

```
   if (inputStream != null) {
        prepStmt.setBinaryStream(index, inputStream, inputStream.available());
    } else {
        prepStmt.setNull(index);
    }
```